# Multi select employees in Employee Time Activities

Tags: acumatica

I was trying to enable multi-select for Owner in Employee Time Activities and wanted to try based on below article.

https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/01/multi-select-selector.html

Then override view like below:
https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/11/sql-in-operator-in-bql.html

However, after I added  ValidateValue = false in field:
[image]

I am getting this error.
[image]

I looked at the custom attribute and I don't think it could be replaced with anything keeping the same implementation.

So, is there any other way I can accomplish multi select feature to allow display Employee Time Activities for selected employees at once besides the ideas mentioned above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issue is that DimensionSelector is different than Selector.
Secondary thing to keep in mind that when you do Multiselector you would need to update the field that holds the values to have a longer length. The way a multiselector works is that it stored the saved values as a ; (semicolon) separated string. so if the field was 10 long you would want to expand to whatever you expect the max number of selected values would be, e.g. 40 would be 480, 40x10 + 40x2, 10 being the original size, 2 being a semicolon and space. (hope that makes sense :) )

Next you would have to update all the functional business logic to then parse that string and loop each, in this case, employee for the functions.

I am speaking very generically here. So not sure what you're actually attempting to do here, but one would assume that if you were selecting multiple employees you would want records to reflect accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I think the DAC Field length wouldn't have been problem here however the major problem would be the DimensionSelector which I think would be a big issue overriding the behaviour. Now I am not sure, if it's even worth the change. It would be really nice if Acumatica would have provided the multi select option rather than going through such workarounds.